# Only when running Reddit bot using pyinstaller '.exe' file: AttributeError: '_NotSet' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, reddit, praw

For some reason I keep getting the following error (during login) whenever I try to run the pyinstaller-generated .exe file for my reddit bot:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 11, in run
  File "login.py", line 14, in do
  File "praw\reddit.py", line 129, in __init__
  File "praw\config.py", line 72, in __init__
  File "praw\config.py", line 98, in _initialize_attributes
  File "praw\config.py", line 31, in _config_boolean
AttributeError: '_NotSet' object has no attribute 'lower'
Failed to execute script main
```

And yet everything is fine when I run it in PyCharm -- no errors and everything is 100% functional.

I've only got Python 3.4 installed, no other versions.

Here's the login code (with auth values changed):

```
import praw

username = '4_the_wolf_x'
password = 'password'
client_id = 'xxxx_xxxxxxxxxx'
client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
APP_UA = '4thewolfx.com'

def do():
    session = praw.Reddit(
            username = username,
            password = password,
            client_id = client_id,
            client_secret = client_secret,
            user_agent = APP_UA
            )
    return session
```

Seems pretty straight-forward. I don't really know what the error in this case is referring to. Would appreciate any help

Comment: From what I see, `short_url` not being defined can cause this to happen. Are you creating a config object in main.py? https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/tree/master/praw

Comment: @JacobIRR No config object being created in main.py; Here's the code in main.py: session = login.do()